# find the closest element of parent element

Tags: jquery, closest

HTML structure looks like this: `title > ul > li > a`. After clicking on the anchor tag, I need to `.slideToggle()` on the `.content` element, which is closest to the `.title`.

My current js for it looks like this and it doesn't work. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pool/ad9bz/6/)

```
$(function(){ 
  $('.title > ul > li > a').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('.content').slideToggle();
  })  
})
```

Comment: Can't help without HTML.

Comment: check the fiddle please.

Comment: My bad, still should have added to the question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.content` is not in the same tree as your selector, therefore `.closest` wont find it. You need to use a combo of `.closest` and `.next`

```
$(this).closest('.title').next(".content").slideToggle();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ad9bz/5/

Also, be sure to include jQuery in your fiddle next time!

Comment: @MilindAnantwar  SO asked me to wait for five more mins to accept it.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$(this).parents('.title').next('.content').slideToggle();
```